# I cant figure out the problem with my facebook tags?

Tags: html, facebook, web, tags

this is how I did my tags and I placed them inside, and still, Facebook won't recognize them...

How I put the tags:

[image: how i put the tags]

What Facebook says

[image: What facebook says]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZuyQ.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZuyQ.jpg)

Comment: Without the URL that you censured it is impossible to say.

Comment: Looks like issue solved by now? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=http://bikecoin.co